# Indoor map in android

Tags: android, android-layout, dictionary

I am trying to create an indoor map like the below image.This is scrollable/moving in the whole screen.I am not getting what is a right approach to create it .Is this a Google  Indoor Map ?

How can i create buttons over an image like this map ?

Please Suggest.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide more information how to make indoor map? Did you use Google indoor map or OpenStreetMap ? –

Comment: Did u used google indoor map. can u just answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449261/indoor-map-upload-status-is-reviewed-in-android

Comment: @Rao's link is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by creating an Imagemap using html and embedded that html in a WebView.

Comment: could you please provide more information how to make indoor map? Did you use Google indoor map or OpenStreetMap ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a standard image file / breaking your image into tiles, then making a custom `View` which loads your map image and captures all the touch events for scrolling and click detection.

If you want clickable overlays you could take two approaches:

1. Include the buttons in the source image and look for hotspots in the image when it is clicked.
2. Create a list of co-ordinates within your image to overlay a button graphic, when a click is detected you can compare the position of the click with this list (and a small margin for error).

Personally I prefer the second method and have used it successfully in several projects requiring maps with clickable points of interest.

Comment: Both solutions are not easy to implement but still works. Cheers! But is there a more updated approach?